# How to skip a whole test suit in gTest?

Tags: c++, googletest

I have a few test suites, and I want the user to be able to input the test suit packages he wants to run via command line (I'm using a custom script, so not via gtest command arguments). I want every suite to be able to be a part of any number of packages - and I would rather not create a mapping pf package to test name to use gtest-filter.

How I was thinking to do it - in every suite, implement

```
static void SetUpTestSuit()
{
    if (!_shouldRunSuite())
    {
        // Stop execution of the whole suit here;
    }
}
```

I was expecting to be able to do this with GTEST_SKIP(), but it doesn't work.

I could do something like this:

```
static void SetUpTestSuite()
{
    if(!_shouldRunSuite())
    {
        m_shouldRunTest = false;
    }
}

void SetUp() override
{
    if(!m_shouldRunTest)
    {
        GTEST_SKIP();
    }
}
```

But this means calling every single test, doing the bool check, and skipping - which could get to a hefty overhead if there are a few hundred tests  in the suits that should be skipped.

Is there a way I can do this without skipping every single test in the suite separately?

Comment: please claify more , and need reproducible sample!

Comment: `GTEST_SKIP();` is for exceptional situation. It is weird you need to do this for whole test suite. Can you explain why? Maybe there is better alternative?

Comment: `I want the user to be able to input the test suit packages he wants to run via command line` this is possible out of the box by: `unitTest --gtest_filter=RunThosTest.*:-DoNotRunThisOne.*`

Comment: So you want user to use command line to filter tests, but you can't allow user to use command line to filter out tests? Why can't you modify build script to pass user arguments to the binary? If you really can't, you could always replace `argv` with something more to your liking or even `setenv` to add `GTEST_FILTER` from within your `main`, before you call `InitGoogleTest`

Comment: @MarekR I mentioned I don't want to use the test/suit name as a filter - in particular, I don't want the user to have to edit the filter every time a new test suite is added to one package or the other.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen can I filter with GTEST_FILTER by anything other than the test names? Like groups, or packages? I wanted to avoid the need to add the suit name to a list, and rather use the opposite approach - for the suit to know which packages are relevant to it. Admittedly, since there seems to be no simple way to implement it, it might be the wrong approach...

Comment: GTest offers grouping in form of test suites (test fixtures). `TEST(X, Y)` (or `TEST_F`) will have name `X.Y` and you can filter e.g. by `X.*` to only run tests from suite `X`. It is theoretically possible to name your tests whatever you want using `RegisterTest`, but that's highly inconvenient. If you need more involved naming than test suites and test cases offered by GTest, you will need to write something yourself.

Answer (score 0):

register test cases manually and do not use google tests auto-discovery. registering test cases manually [doc](https://google.github.io/googletest/advanced.html#registering-tests-programmatically) is available

The TEST macros handle the vast majority of all use cases, but there are few where runtime registration logic is required. For those cases, the framework provides the ::testing::RegisterTest that allows callers to register arbitrary tests dynamically.

This is an advanced API only to be used when the TEST macros are insufficient. The macros should be preferred when possible, as they avoid most of the complexity of calling this function.

It provides the following signature:

```
template <typename Factory>
TestInfo* RegisterTest(const char* test_suite_name, const char* test_name,
                       const char* type_param, const char* value_param,
                       const char* file, int line, Factory factory);
```

The factory argument is a factory callable (move-constructible) object or function pointer that creates a new instance of the Test object. It handles ownership to the caller. The signature of the callable is Fixture*(), where Fixture is the test fixture class for the test. All tests registered with the same test_suite_name must return the same fixture type. This is checked at runtime.

The framework will infer the fixture class from the factory and will call the SetUpTestSuite and TearDownTestSuite for it.

Must be called before RUN_ALL_TESTS() is invoked, otherwise behavior is undefined.

Use case example:

```
class MyFixture : public testing::Test {
 public:
  // All of these optional, just like in regular macro usage.
  static void SetUpTestSuite() { ... }
  static void TearDownTestSuite() { ... }
  void SetUp() override { ... }
  void TearDown() override { ... }
};

class MyTest : public MyFixture {
 public:
  explicit MyTest(int data) : data_(data) {}
  void TestBody() override { ... }

 private:
  int data_;
};

void RegisterMyTests(const std::vector<int>& values) {
  for (int v : values) {
    testing::RegisterTest(
        "MyFixture", ("Test" + std::to_string(v)).c_str(), nullptr,
        std::to_string(v).c_str(),
        __FILE__, __LINE__,
        // Important to use the fixture type as the return type here.
        [=]() -> MyFixture* { return new MyTest(v); });
  }
}
...
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  std::vector<int> values_to_test = LoadValuesFromConfig();
  RegisterMyTests(values_to_test);
  ...
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```